# GHUnit using non-required do-while loop?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing

I was looking through the GHUnit source code, and noticed that they wrap most/all of their testing functions in `do-while` loops, but the while condition will always evaluate to `false`. Why is this?

Here's their listing for `#define GHAssertEqualStrings (a1, a2, description, ...)`

```
do { \
    @try {\
        id a1value = (a1); \
        id a2value = (a2); \
        if (a1value == a2value) continue; \
        if ([a1value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && \
        [a2value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && \
        [a1value compare:a2value options:0] == NSOrderedSame) continue; \
        [self failWithException:[NSException ghu_failureInEqualityBetweenObject: a1value \
        andObject: a2value \
        inFile: [NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] \
        atLine: __LINE__ \
        withDescription: GHComposeString(description, ##__VA_ARGS__)]]; \
    }\
    @catch (id anException) {\
        [self failWithException:[NSException ghu_failureInRaise:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"(%s) == (%s)", #a1, #a2] \
        exception:anException \
        inFile:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] \
        atLine:__LINE__ \
        withDescription:GHComposeString(description, ##__VA_ARGS__)]]; \
    }\

} while(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further inspection, it's quite obvious that they are using the do while loop to their advantage. The author is using the `continue` statement at various places in order to alter the normal order of execution. You could think of it as a simpler/less hacky `goto` statement.